# Configuration inside a gem's asset not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, erb

I created a gem called [Supportator](https://github.com/archdaily/supportator) that puts a warning modal when the browser version is not Supported. Currently its accepting a configuration hash where you can pass the last version not supported of each browser.

### The Code

This is the initializer inside my application `config/initializers/supportator.rb`

```
   Supportator.configure({:chrome => 30, :ie => 11})
```

This is the configuration file of the gem `lib/supportator.rb`:

```
   require "supportator/version"
   require "engine"

   module Supportator

     @config = {
                 :chrome => 14,
                 :safari => 5,
                 :firefox => 3,
                 :ie => 9,
                 :opera => 12
     }

     @valid_config_keys = @config.keys

     def self.configure(opts = {})
       opts.each {|k,v| @config[k.to_sym] = v if @valid_config_keys.include? k.to_sym}
     end

     def self.config
       @config
     end

   end
```

This is part of the js.erb file that triggers the modal of the gem `lib/assets/javascripts/supportator.js.erb`:

```
    ...

    if (browserName == "Chrome" && majorVersion >= <%= Supportator.config[:chrome] %>)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Safari" && majorVersion >= <%= Supportator.config[:safari] %>)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Firefox" && majorVersion >= <%= Supportator.config[:firefox] %>)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && majorVersion >= <%= Supportator.config[:ie] %>)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Opera" && majorVersion >= <%= Supportator.config[:opera] %>)
        supported = true;
    else
        supported = false;

    ....
```

### The Problem

When I see the code after the pre-compilation the result is:

```
    ...

    if (browserName == "Chrome" && majorVersion >= 14)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Safari" && majorVersion >= 5)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Firefox" && majorVersion >= 3)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && majorVersion >= 9)
        supported = true;
    else if (browserName == "Opera" && majorVersion >= 12)
        supported = true;
    else
        supported = false;

    ....
```

But when I put in the console `Supportator.config[:ie]` the result is 12.

Clearly in the pre-compilation of the js.erb the configuration is being ignored. Anyone has ideas of why it could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be helpful but I'm not able to reproduce your bug.  Your gem is acting as expected when I `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and then `rails s`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user2624592, are you using the same initializer as I am?

Comment: Yes, I am. I do notice if I change the values in the initializer it has no effect.  Maybe the initializer is used only once?